# Generate Firebase token in Behat test

Tags: php, firebase, jwt, behat, api-platform.com

I've an installation of API-Platform where user are authenticated using a Firebase JWT token.

You can see a very similar application here https://github.com/hpatoio/api-platform-jwt-firebase

I now want to write a Behat test and I need to create a valid JWT token to use in tests. The problem is that I cannot use the approach describer [here](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/jwt/#testing-with-behat) because I don't have `User` in my application.

```
// From the link above

$user = new User(); <<< User are from Firebase in my application
$user->setUsername('admin');
$user->setPassword('ATestPassword');
$user->setEmail('test@test.com');

$this->manager->persist($user);
$this->manager->flush();

$token = $this->jwtManager->create($user);
```

How can I create a JWT I can use in tests ?

Comment: You can create a method that generates this token, see here the principle https://jwt.io/

Comment: Are you sure you need to generate the token yourself, maybe you need to do a post with email + password that will return your JWT. Check the frontend and see what request are done for authentication.